# Score Reporting problems

Tags: c

Can u guys help me how to make a simple report calculation

1st score x 20%

2nd score x 40%

3rd score x 40%

Sample :

Input :

> 65 56 100

Output :

> 75.00

My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

int score1, score2, score3;
float amount;
float n;

float percent1 = 0.2;
float percent2 = 0.4;
float percent3 = 0.4;
scanf("%f %f %f",&n, &n, &n);

score1 = (float)n*percent1;
score2 = (float)n*percent2;
score3 = (float)n*percent3;

amount = score1+score2+score3;
printf("%.2f\n", amount);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

my input:

> 65 56 100

my output:

> 100.00

u can see it there, the output must be 92.00

is there any mistakes?

Help me pls, ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same variable (`n`) for all three input values. You need a separate variable for each input value. Use the `score` variables to store the values and then use them in a single calculation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int score1, score2, score3;
  float amount;
/* Variable 'n' not required, since not used. */
  float n;

  float percent1 = 0.2;
  float percent2 = 0.4;
  float percent3 = 0.4;

  scanf("%f %f %f",&score1, &score2, &score3);

  amount = (score1 * percent1) + (score2 * percent2) + (score3 * percent3);
  printf("%.2f\n", amount);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```